# Plone/Apache custom error page

Tags: apache, plone, httpd.conf

I'm trying to generate custom error pages for 404 and 500 errors. [I've tried adding `ErrorDocument 404 "My custom error message"` to httpd.conf](http://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/front-end/apache.html#custom-500-internal-error-page) but it hasn't had any effect. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

NameVirtualHost *:80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
    ErrorDocument 500 "testing custom 500 error"
    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.google.com
    ErrorDocument 503 http://www.google.com
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    ErrorDocument 500 "testing custom 500 error"
    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.google.com
    ErrorDocument 503 http://www.google.com
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 500 "testing custom 500 error"
    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.google.com
    ErrorDocument 503 http://www.google.com
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 500 "testing custom 500 error"
    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.google.com
    ErrorDocument 503 http://www.google.com
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ***
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule   ***
    RewriteRule   ***
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /showemails ***
    ProxyPassReverse /showemails ***
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / ***
    ProxyPassReverse / ***
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /security /
    AllowOverride All
    ErrorDocument 500 /core/error
    ErrorDocument 404 /core/error
    ErrorDocument 503 http://www.google.com
</VirtualHost>

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're lacking a [`ProxyErrorOverride On` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride):

> Description: Override error pages for proxied content
>
> This
>   directive is useful for reverse-proxy setups, where you want to have a
>   common look and feel on the error pages seen by the end user. [...]
>
> This directive does not affect the processing of informational (1xx),
>   normal success (2xx), or redirect (3xx) responses.

Comment: just a sidenote: plone - by default - has a very expensive 404 page which performs a site search. overwriting this page in nginx does not save resources on the zope server.
so it might be a good idea to [customize the error page too](http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Customizing-the-Zope-404-page-td7571630.html)

Comment: @fRiSi: yes. (If I recall, the 404 page has a 30x case, too, though, in case a page was previously known under that URL, so I guess the OP has to think about how much they want to chop out.)

Answer (score 0):

Eamonn, I have a solution for you :-)

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/sitename
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin plone@localhost
        ServerName sitename.domain

        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-sitename.log combined
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-sitename.log

        # Custom errors for the proxied zope server
        ProxyErrorOverride On
        ErrorDocument 500 'Sorry, our script crashed'
        ErrorDocument 404 'http://google.com/404'

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/sitename/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: remove AllowOverride - not needed